# Shell script + time dependency

Tags: linux, shell, time, service, while-loop

I wanted to write a shell script for the following:
I want to check if a service is running, if it is running then exit 1, or else after 5 min of it not running, exit -1.
something like:

```
while(for 5 minutes) {
if service running, exit 1
}
exit -1   //service is not running even after 5 minutes, so exit -1.
```

I am able to check the condition that if service is running or not, but not able to add the time constraint part.

This is what i attempted

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep tomcat7 | wc -l) > 0 )); 
then
echo "running"
else
echo "NOT running"
fi
```

Comment: Post what you have tried till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `bash` [`sleep`](http://ss64.com/bash/sleep.html) command. An excerpt from the `man` page:-

You could provide `sleep 5m` in your script to wait for 5 minutes and do an action.

```
NAME
       sleep - delay for a specified amount of time

DESCRIPTION
       Pause  for  NUMBER  seconds.   SUFFIX  may be 's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.  Unlike most implementations that require NUMBER be an
       integer, here NUMBER may be an arbitrary floating point number.  Given two or more arguments, pause for the amount of time specified by the sum of their values.
```

A proper way to your solution would be:-

```
#!/bin/bash
maxAttempts=0          
maxCounter=2     # Number of attempts can be controlled by this variable    

 while [ "$maxAttempts" -lt "$maxCounter" ]; do
    if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "tomcat7" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "tomcat7 service running, "
        exit 1
    else
        maxAttempts=$((maxAttempts+1))
        sleep 5m                           # The script waits for 5 minutes before exiting with error code '-1'
    fi
done

exit -1
```

The `if` condition works when the `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "tomcat7"` returns a command success error code for which the condition passes. `> /dev/null` to suppress all standard outpur(stdout, stderr) to `/dev/null` so that we can work only with the exit codes of the command provided.

Comment: The script should check after 5 minutes also (ideally continously for 5 minutes) is the service is running or not, and if it starts to run within 5 minutes, exit 1, and if it doesnt work within 5 minutes, then exit -1

Comment: So you want it in a loop to constantly poll to see if the service is running every 5 minutes continuously right?

Comment: I want it in a loop to check if service is running, if it does then exit 1. The loop runs for 5 minutes. If it doesnt work in 5 minutes, the loop will end and exit -1.

Comment: @AdityaJain: Please look into http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html for future-reference! You cannot expect straight-forward answers like mine in the future from the community.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I am a newbie and hence needed this. Will research more everytime before asking anything from this community.
And yes, it did solve my problem. I have decresed the sleep time and increased the maximum value the variable can take.